# Using iterative functions to specifically sort a list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, iterators, iteration

The following code sort the list `li` in a such way that consecutive terms $t_n,t_{n+1}$ are of the from `...{x_,y_}, {y_,z_}...`. i.e. $first(t_{n+1})=last(t_{n})$

I suspect there may be a nicer code that would use one of these: `FoldList`, `NestList` or other iterative functions. (or maybe some of the functions used on graphs like `FindPath`)

I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Input:

```
li = {{102, 101}, {5, 6}, {69, 82}, {111, 110}, {48, 35}, {92, 
    79}, {94, 95}, {72, 59}, {152, 165}, {112, 113}, {7, 20}, {88, 
    75}, {53, 40}, {8, 7}, {11, 24}, {109, 96}, {116, 115}, {29, 
    42}, {58, 57}, {2, 15}, {51, 50}, {47, 60}, {120, 107}, {166, 
    167}, {15, 16}, {73, 86}, {9, 8}, {12, 11}, {82, 81}, {70, 
    71}, {133, 132}, {56, 69}, {57, 56}, {125, 124}, {149, 148}, {27, 
    14}, {14, 1}, {165, 166}, {68, 55}, {128, 129}, {19, 32}, {40, 
    41}, {96, 97}, {39, 26}, {18, 5}, {49, 48}, {157, 144}, {20, 
    21}, {135, 134}, {137, 138}, {75, 62}, {139, 140}, {99, 112}, {34,
     33}, {97, 98}, {17, 18}, {81, 68}, {43, 44}, {64, 65}, {54, 
    67}, {90, 91}, {105, 92}, {145, 146}, {146, 159}, {160, 
    161}, {167, 168}, {85, 84}, {158, 157}, {148, 147}, {151, 
    150}, {98, 85}, {31, 30}, {86, 87}, {130, 117}, {1, 2}, {13, 
    12}, {140, 153}, {132, 145}, {115, 102}, {143, 130}, {113, 
    114}, {168, 169}, {159, 158}, {4, 17}, {16, 3}, {44, 45}, {101, 
    88}, {142, 143}, {108, 121}, {21, 34}, {136, 135}, {25, 38}, {74, 
    73}, {91, 78}, {63, 76}, {52, 39}, {119, 120}, {23, 10}, {164, 
    151}, {41, 28}, {78, 77}, {6, 19}, {10, 9}, {138, 139}, {134, 
    133}, {131, 118}, {22, 23}, {117, 104}, {147, 160}, {155, 
    154}, {37, 36}, {83, 70}, {60, 61}, {153, 152}, {87, 100}, {59, 
    58}, {24, 25}, {106, 105}, {118, 119}, {42, 43}, {38, 51}, {129, 
    142}, {67, 66}, {89, 90}, {127, 126}, {163, 164}, {50, 37}, {126, 
    125}, {100, 99}, {154, 141}, {150, 137}, {32, 31}, {71, 72}, {114,
     127}, {46, 47}, {77, 64}, {79, 80}, {162, 163}, {65, 52}, {55, 
    54}, {76, 89}, {28, 27}, {161, 162}, {3, 4}, {62, 63}, {123, 
    136}, {156, 155}, {144, 131}, {35, 22}, {122, 109}, {103, 
    116}, {107, 106}, {95, 108}, {80, 93}, {61, 74}, {110, 123}, {33, 
    46}, {141, 128}, {169, 156}, {121, 122}, {66, 53}, {30, 29}, {104,
     103}, {26, 13}, {93, 94}, {36, 49}, {124, 111}, {84, 83}};
start = {{149, 148}};
Table[start = Join[start, Cases[li, {start[[-1, -1]], x_}]], {i, 
   300}][[-1]]
```

Output:

```
{{149, 148}, {148, 147}, {147, 160}, {160, 161}, {161, 162}, {162, 
  163}, {163, 164}, {164, 151}, {151, 150}, {150, 137}, {137, 
  138}, {138, 139}, {139, 140}, {140, 153}, {153, 152}, {152, 
  165}, {165, 166}, {166, 167}, {167, 168}, {168, 169}, {169, 
  156}, {156, 155}, {155, 154}, {154, 141}, {141, 128}, {128, 
  129}, {129, 142}, {142, 143}, {143, 130}, {130, 117}, {117, 
  104}, {104, 103}, {103, 116}, {116, 115}, {115, 102}, {102, 
  101}, {101, 88}, {88, 75}, {75, 62}, {62, 63}, {63, 76}, {76, 
  89}, {89, 90}, {90, 91}, {91, 78}, {78, 77}, {77, 64}, {64, 
  65}, {65, 52}, {52, 39}, {39, 26}, {26, 13}, {13, 12}, {12, 
  11}, {11, 24}, {24, 25}, {25, 38}, {38, 51}, {51, 50}, {50, 
  37}, {37, 36}, {36, 49}, {49, 48}, {48, 35}, {35, 22}, {22, 
  23}, {23, 10}, {10, 9}, {9, 8}, {8, 7}, {7, 20}, {20, 21}, {21, 
  34}, {34, 33}, {33, 46}, {46, 47}, {47, 60}, {60, 61}, {61, 
  74}, {74, 73}, {73, 86}, {86, 87}, {87, 100}, {100, 99}, {99, 
  112}, {112, 113}, {113, 114}, {114, 127}, {127, 126}, {126, 
  125}, {125, 124}, {124, 111}, {111, 110}, {110, 123}, {123, 
  136}, {136, 135}, {135, 134}, {134, 133}, {133, 132}, {132, 
  145}, {145, 146}, {146, 159}, {159, 158}, {158, 157}, {157, 
  144}, {144, 131}, {131, 118}, {118, 119}, {119, 120}, {120, 
  107}, {107, 106}, {106, 105}, {105, 92}, {92, 79}, {79, 80}, {80, 
  93}, {93, 94}, {94, 95}, {95, 108}, {108, 121}, {121, 122}, {122, 
  109}, {109, 96}, {96, 97}, {97, 98}, {98, 85}, {85, 84}, {84, 
  83}, {83, 70}, {70, 71}, {71, 72}, {72, 59}, {59, 58}, {58, 
  57}, {57, 56}, {56, 69}, {69, 82}, {82, 81}, {81, 68}, {68, 
  55}, {55, 54}, {54, 67}, {67, 66}, {66, 53}, {53, 40}, {40, 
  41}, {41, 28}, {28, 27}, {27, 14}, {14, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 15}, {15, 
  16}, {16, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 17}, {17, 18}, {18, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 
  19}, {19, 32}, {32, 31}, {31, 30}, {30, 29}, {29, 42}, {42, 
  43}, {43, 44}, {44, 45}}
```

**Update:**

Or if you want to test the code on a random list `li`:

```
origli = Partition[RandomSample[Range[100]], 2, 1];
li = RandomSample[origli]
pstart = (Reverse /@ Tally[Flatten[%]] // Sort)[[{1, 2}, 2]];
start = Cases[li, {Alternatives @@ pstart, x_}];
sortedli = 
 Table[start = Join[start, Cases[li, {start[[-1, -1]], x_}]], {i, 
    300}][[-1]]
sortedli == origli
Clear[origli, li, pstart, start, sortedli]
```

Comment: E.g. with patterns: rule = {x1___, y1 : {_, x3_}, x4__, y2 : {x3_, _}, x5___} :> {x1, y1, 
    y2, x4, x5};
li //. rule

Comment: It does not seem to work... Is there a typo? Or what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: The stack exchange editor changes the pattern. I will put it in the answer window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. TopologicalSort**

```
path1 = Partition[TopologicalSort[DirectedEdge @@@ li], 2, 1]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**2. FindHamiltonianPath**

```
path2 = Partition[Reverse @ FindHamiltonianPath[li], 2, 1];
```

Alternatively,

```
path3  = Partition[FindHamiltonianPath[DirectedEdge @@@ li], 2, 1];
```

**3. RelationGraph**

```
rg = RelationGraph[#[[2]] == #2[[1]] &, li]

path4 = FindHamiltonianPath @ rg ;
```

We can use `rg` in several additional ways to get the desired list:

```
root = First @ VertexList[rg, _?(VertexInDegree[rg, #] == 0 &)]; 

path5 = VertexOutComponent[rg, root];

path6 =  SortBy[GraphDistance[rg, root, #] &] @ VertexList[rg];

path7 = SortBy[Length[VertexInComponent[rg, {#}]] &] @ VertexList[rg];
```

**4. Nest**

```
ClearAll[firstPair, nextPair, addPair]
firstPair[pairs_] := FirstCase[pairs, {a_, b_} /; Count[pairs, {_, a}] == 0]
nextPair[pairs_][{a_, b_}] := FirstCase[{b, _}]@pairs
addPair[pairs_][{a___, b_}] := {a, b, nextPair[pairs][b]}

path8 = Nest[addPair[li], {firstPair[li]}, Length @ li - 1];
```

**5. FixedPoint + SequenceReplace**

```
path9 = FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[{{a_, b_}, c___, {b_, d_}} | {{b_, d_}, 
     c___, {a_, b_}} :> Sequence[{a, b}, {b, d}, c]], li];

path1 == path2 == path3 == path4 == path5 == path6 == path7 == path8 == path9
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Almost perfect... but it finds `...{x_,y_}, {y_,z_}...` or `...{y_,x_}, {z_,y_}...`. it depends on the order of `GraphPeriphery` whether `FindPath` works on `{{149, 148}, {44, 45}}` or on `{{44, 45},{149, 148}}`

Comment: @azerbajdzan, please see the new version.

Answer (score 0):

```
rule = {x1___, y1 : {_, x3_}, x4__, y2 : {x3_, _}, x5___} :> {x1, y1, 
   y2, x4, x5}; 
Sort[li] //. rule
```

Comment: Still does not work. Because it produces such results as for example: `...{94, 57}, {57, 9}, {99, 23}, {23, 65}, {65, 67}...`. But `9` and `99` are not the same.

Comment: Even weirder one: `...{7, 25}, {25, 3}, {3, 85}, {44, 96}, {96, 11}, {11, 33}...`. `85` and `44` are no the same.

Comment: I do not think this answer deserved a down vote. It sort the list almost as required but not entire list. It is like it sort it by several chunks. Maybe it can be fixed.

Comment: What data are you using. I can't see what you say.

Comment: You can use it on original `li` list or random `li` that is in the update.

Comment: You will not get by your rule the output that is in my OP.

Comment: Using the original li, I can not see anything like  {3, 85}, {44, 96} or  {3, 85}, {44, 96}. I did not try to reproduce your data, I tried to make consecutive pairs as you specified. What more do you want?

Comment: Just apply your rule to the `li` and search the output for consecutive terms `...{a,b},{x,y}...` for which `b!=x`. You will find some... If your code worked correctly you would not find any.

Comment: "I did not try to reproduce your data" - But the correct result is unique. It is just one, not several.

Comment: O.k. I see. It is necessary to first sort your data then it is o.k.